# Trigger function when an order is made in Shopware6

Tags: php, symfony, event-handling, shopware, subscriber

I am having a little misunderstanding while trying to trigger a function after the creation of a new order in **shopware6** but nothing happens.

My syntax is maybe so *Shopware5* because I am really new to SW6.

Here is my code (only for testing) :

```
<?php

namespace Emakers\TransmissionPlugin\Subscriber;

use Enlight_Hook_HookArgs;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class OrderSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        // return the subscribed events, their methods and priorities
        return [
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => [
                ['OrderEvents::ORDER_WRITTEN_EVENT::RESPONSE' => 'onOrderCheckout'],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function onOrderCheckout(Enlight_Hook_HookArgs $args): void
    {
        die('TEST OK');
    }
}
```

Is there somewhere I can find all the events related to **orders**? Maybe the one I am using is incorrect.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was coming from the services.xml file, You have to add this to your subscriber service :

```
<tag name="kernel.event_listener" />            
<tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct(EntityRepositoryInterface $orderRepository)
{
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        //CartEvents::CHECKOUT_ORDER_PLACED => 'onCheckoutOrderPlaced'
        OrderEvents::ORDER_WRITTEN_EVENT => 'onOrderCheckout'
    ];
}
```

Shopware and PHP is completely new to me but the above code is working for me to fire a event
Hey can you give codes to get the order details ?

Comment: @tgallei How can i get the order details in onOrderCheckout().. Please i need the code

Comment: you have to send $event as a parameter and make a dump of it like this : 

`public function onOrderCheckout($event) { var_dump($event); die('dump'); }`